# Simple Swift Combine subscribing to textDidChangeNotification

Tags: swift, frp, combine

I'm having trouble getting the most simple implementation of the Combine pattern to work, subscribing to a UITextField textDidChangeNotification.

```
import UIKit
import Combine

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let textField = UITextField()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(textField)
        textField.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
        textField.placeholder = "Search"

        let sub = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification, object: textField)
            .sink { (notification) in
                print("123")
        }
    }

}
```

I must be missing something super simple, but this basic pattern is exactly copied from the Documentation and other tutorials.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `sink` call returns an `AnyCancellable`, a ARC managed object which models the lifetime of your subscription.

You assigned this cancellable token to the local variable `sub`, whose lifetime ends at last usage of the `sub` variable (no later than the end of the `viewDidLoad()` function's scope). This is causing your subscription to be cancelled early, before anything could have happened.

If you want your subscription to last longer, you need to extend the lifetime of `sub`, perhaps by storing it as a property of your `ViewController` object.

Comment: Alexander you are a gentleman and a scholar.  Thanks for the answer, marked as correct.

Comment: @TinLuong hardly, I've just struggled with this one before. :) You should also look into [`AnyCancellable.store(in set: inout Set<AnyCancellable>)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anycancellable/3333294-store), which can simplify your code when you have lots of different lifetimes to manage. It makes `Set<AnyCancellable>` work similar to RxSwift's `DisposeBag`.